# can't show custom AnnotationView's image immediately

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

PhotoAnnotation is conforming MKAnnotation, PhotoAnnotationView is subclass of MKAnnotationView.
PhotoAnnotation has an image property.

the problem is the custom annotation's image don't show on the mapview once i open the app. I have to pan around and move to somewhere, then move back to the original area, then the image will be showed.

using MKPinAnnotation has no such problem. the image of pin will show straight away.

I have no clue in how to fix it. please help me. thanks so much.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? PhotoAnnotation {
        let identifier = "pin"
        let view: PhotoAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? PhotoAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation

            dequeuedView.image = annotation.image

            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = PhotoAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = false
            view.image = nil
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note of this part, 'view.image = nil'... since on your first load where there is no annotation yet created before, it falls to that code where you set your image as nil. Handle that and you're good.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? PhotoAnnotation {
        let identifier = "pin"
        let view: PhotoAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? PhotoAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation

            dequeuedView.image = annotation.image

            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = PhotoAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = false
            view.image = UIImage() // do something here...
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: no problem. you're welcome. just mark your question as answered if it is already answered.